# list.pop() is removing two items at a time, but i want to delete the current one only

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want to delete one item at a time from list but using remove(), pop() getting two items deleted.

```
Fruits = ['apple','hello','banana','lichi','mango']
for item in Fruits:
    print(item)
    Fruits.remove(item)
```

The answer i m getting is:
apple
banana 
mango

how to delete just one item from list.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're iterating over a list which you're removing items from at the same time.

```
for i in range(len(Fruit)):
  item = Fruit.pop()
  print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
item = Fruits.pop()
```

to remove one item from the list

```
Fruits.remove('mango')
```

to remove 'mango' from the list

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
Fruits = ['apple','hello','banana','lichi','mango']
while Fruits:
    print(Fruits.pop())
```

In your code sample, you can imagine that in the first loop, when `'apple'` was removed from the list. the Fruits was changed to `['hello','banana','lichi','mango']`. So, in the second loop, `'banana'` was extracted and removed as the second item and `'hello'` was bypassed. So, you know, avoid changing size of the list in `for` loop.

updated according to request:

```
Fruits = ['apple','hello','banana','lichi','mango']
i = 0
while i < len(Fruits):
    item = Fruits[i]
    print(item)
    if item == 'apple':
        Fruits.remove(item)
    else:
        i += 1
```

The `for` loop in Python does not like C/C++. It is actually transferred to go through the iterator. It is hard to be controlled precisely. So, `while` clause is used here. But `while` clause should be avoided because it is easy to cause dead loop.

Comment: thank you for your reply...but what if i want to delete a particular fruit say "banana" from the list ...and want to iterate through with remaining fruit list

Comment: thanks ...got a clue from your reply...it worked....